# Passing a variable index to flutter widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter and I'm trying to build a calendar-like view.

I'm using some logic to generate a list of weeks, displayed as rows, that themselves are lists of days (base widgets).

I encountered a road block passing a simple index to the single Day widgets in order to display the number of the day.

While I've learnt how to pass them to the widget themselves through their constructor:
`CalendarDay({this.monthDay});`, Dart keeps complaining that since they're being generated through logic the index values are not constants.

Logic I use to generate the List of List of CalendarDay Widgets:

```
    for(int rows =1,daysAdded=1; rows<=7;rows++) {
      for(int y=1;y<=7;y++){
        if(rows > 1 || y >= firstOfMonthWeekday){
          print("Adding day $daysAdded to week nr. $rows");
          final String str = daysAdded.toString();

          // This is where I try to pass the index to the CalendarDay Widget
          weeklyRow.add(new CalendarDay(monthDay: str)); 
          daysAdded++;
          if(daysAdded>daysInThisMonth){
            done = true;
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      monthWeeksDays.add(weeklyRow);
      weeklyRow = [];
      print('Days in week $rows: ${monthWeeksDays[rows-1].length}');
      if(done)
        break;
    }
```

The CalendarDay widget itself:

```
class CalendarDay extends StatelessWidget {
  final String monthDay;
  CalendarDay({this.monthDay});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return SizedBox(
      width: screenWidth/7,
      height: screenWidth/7,
      child: const DecoratedBox(
        decoration: BoxDecoration( color: Colors.blue),
        child: Center(
          child: Text(monthDay),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I've already tried converting CalendarDay to a StatefulWidget to see if that would have let me use a non constant value but it still required the value to be constant, even when I removed the final keyword from the class declaration.

Outside of doing without the indexes I'm not sure how to proceed, if someone can just point me to a way to solve the problem I'm obviously willing to study it myself. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an idiot, I had copied some code to create colored boxes as a placeholder and it took me multiple hours to notice that I was declaring the DecoratedBox as `const`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `const` right before `CalendarDay({this.monthDay});`:

```
class CalendarDay extends StatelessWidget {
  final String monthDay;
  const CalendarDay({this.monthDay});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return SizedBox(
      width: screenWidth/7,
      height: screenWidth/7,
      child: const DecoratedBox(
        decoration: BoxDecoration( color: Colors.blue),
        child: Center(
          child: Text(monthDay),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried, still get these two errors: 

- error: Arguments of a constant creation must be constant expressions. (const_with_non_constant_argument at [fridge_app] lib/calendar.dart:17)
- error: Evaluation of this constant expression throws an exception. (const_eval_throws_exception at [fridge_app] lib/calendar.dart:17)

Comment: By adding `new` before `Text(monthDay),` the errors changed to simply: `error: Invalid constant value. (invalid_constant at [fridge_app] lib/calendar.dart:17).`